# High temperature aluminum to copper connection

Tags: electrical, aluminum-wiring

**Summary**
120v Oven power wire connector melted and shorted out. Was going to splice the wires together with high temperature wire nut, but found that internal oven power wires are aluminum and the power cord wires are copper. Oven wire sheathing has 150*C temperature rating. What **high temperature**, aluminum to copper connectors exist?

**More Detail**
I have a GE model J2B912SEK2SS oven that uses 120v power. Was using the oven when arcing started to occur behind the oven. I unplugged the oven, took off the back plates and found this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqFBM.jpg (scroll down and see all 3 pics)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I read that corrosion just happens over time which increases resistance which increases heat which probably melted the connector. I figured I could just cut that melted connector out and wire-nut the wires together. So I bought some high temp 150*C wire nuts and they finally got here today. I cut the melted connector out, stripped the wires about 7/16", and noticed that the RED oven internal wire (pictured in link above) is aluminum. Power wire is copper. Argh.

Then I started going down the copper+aluminum connector rabbit hole and read about some options that appear are NOT going to work for me:

1. Purple Wire nuts specifically for aluminum to copper connections. Can't use these because they're only rated to 105*C
2. AlumiConn connector. Can't use this because it is also only rated to 105*C
3. Squirt some anti-oxidation paste inside the wire nut -- Don't want to use this because it seems super sketchy. This wire obviously gets hot and from what I've read, aluminum and copper expanding at different rates inside a wire nut is not good.

So I'm reaching out to people smarter than me to figure out what I can do here. I'd like to avoid buying a new oven if possible, but if it means that I don't have to worry about starting my home on fire then maybe I will go that route. Thanks all!

**UPDATE**

[image]
[image]

Wire has "3321" written on it, which according to [HERE](https://www.awcwire.com/productspec.aspx?id=ul-3321) is a "Fully annealed tinned copper, flexible stranding". Which I *think* is great news! Will I be okay with just a high temperature wire nut, taped up liberally around where it touches the sheet metal?

Comment: Can you get us a better view of the printing on the wire?

Comment: Does the area of the splice reach 150C?

Comment: Per your latest question about high temp wire nuts , they my work but these are special and I have only seen them in black. Looks like bakealight ? Spelling? You should open a new question as multiple questions and change if the question would violate the site rules.

Answer (score 6):

Parts for that model are still available.  Instead of trying to fabricate your own solution you can buy a new cord with connector for under $30. GE P/N AP4412100.

I'd also inspect the mating connector and replace that component too if it shows damage.

Comment: I REALLY wanted to go this route, except the connector was completely melted on *both* sides, which means I would have to find the female connector somehow (do they have appliance junkyards?).

Answer (score 5):

First I will suggest that the wire is tinned copper there is no such thing as high temp aluminum. 
Fixture wire the cloth braided type wire (tinned) and many times has a thin high temp sleeve over the wire under the cloth is not aluminum and may have melted due to a bad connection.

I have seen folks replace female spade connectors with standard crimp connectors not 900 degree crimps that are needed for elements and after a time of heat cycles the non heat rated connectors start arcing and melt the conductors and even burn the end off of oven elements.

The black connector looks like it got hot but it is still functional. I did not notice anything out of the ordinary on the other photos but would suggest if you have a wiring issue check the elements as they may have failed causing the overheat.

Repairing with “quick disconnects” / spade connectors or butt splices should be done with high temp components.

Comment: Or, it is Nichrome , much more likely in a warm application.

Comment: I have only seen nichrome wire used as a heating element but I guess it is possible.

Comment: Updated my post with more findings. You are correct on the tinned copper!!

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree, most likely tinned copper. I would be concerned about eliminating the connector and running the power cord through the sheet metal. A strain relief might be a suitable alternative if you drill a hole for it.

Comment: You are correct on the tinned copper! Updated my post.
Yes, resting the wire on the sheet metal is not good. Figured I could tape it up really well. I even have a silicone radiator hose I can cut a section off of and shove in there as some kind of redneck bulkhead.